# Paragraph keeps pushing 1 div down

Tags: html, css

Im having an issue with some paragraph text that is pushing one div down. I have 2 rows of 3 divs and its the first div on the first row that is pushing the div below it down on row 2 out of line. I just can work out why it doesnt push the whole row of 3 divs below it down.

Hope someone can shed some light on this for me

Thanks very much

https://jsfiddle.net/8sk3f59m/

```
 <div class="row">
      <div class="one-third">
        <div class="right-arrow">
          <i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <div id="wireframe">
          <img src="img/wireframe.svg" class="icons" />
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod sed do eiusmod</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="one-third">
        <div class="right-arrow">
          <i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <div id="develop">
          <img src="img/coding.svg" class="icons" />
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="one-third">
        <div id="responsive">
          <img src="img/responsive1.svg" class="icons" />
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="one-third">
          <div id="responsive">
            <img src="img/responsive.svg" class="icons" />
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="one-third">
          <div id="responsive">
            <img src="img/responsive.svg" class="icons" />
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod!</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="one-third">
          <div id="responsive">
            <img src="img/responsive.svg" class="icons" />
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>



* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 200;
}

p {
  padding: 10px 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
}

.justify {
  text-align: justify;
}


/*--Basic Setup End--*/


/*--Reusable Content Start--*/

.chart-wrapper {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 5% auto 3% auto;
}

.clearfix {
  zoom: 1
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: '.';
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.long-row {
  width: 85%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.row {
  max-width: 950px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.row {
  zoom: 1;
  /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
}

.row:before,
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.long-row:before,
.long-row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.row:after {
  clear: both;
}

.long-row:after {
  clear: both;
}

.one-half {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  margin: 2% auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.one-third {
  width: 33.333%;
  float: left;
  margin: 2% auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.two-thirds {
  width: 66.667%;
  float: left;
  margin: 2% auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.icon-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.icons {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.section-wrap {
  margin: 4% auto;
}

.icon-heading {
  display: block;
  font-style: normal !important;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 2% 0;
}

.underline {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}


#vision {
  margin: 2% 0;
}

.right-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 25%;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

#wireframe,
#develop,
#responsive,
i {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Are you intentionally imbedding your `.row`s?

Comment: That was the problem! my fault there. How silly am i! Didn't realize the first row ended at the end with the other row embedded in between. It was meant to be just to separate rows. All sorted now so thanks a million for the spot

Answer (score 0):

You're forgetting to include a closing `</div>` for your first `.row`. Including this will fix your height alignment issue.

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8sk3f59m/2/)**

```css
/*--Colors--/*

#00cc00 - Green
#7fe57b - Green Gradient


/*--Basic Setup Start--*/

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 200;
}

p {
  padding: 10px 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
}

.justify {
  text-align: justify;
}


/*--Basic Setup End--*/


/*--Reusable Content Start--*/

.chart-wrapper {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 5% auto 3% auto;
}

.clearfix {
  zoom: 1
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: '.';
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.long-row {
  width: 85%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.row {
  max-width: 950px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.row {
  zoom: 1;
  /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
}

.row:before,
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.long-row:before,
.long-row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.row:after {
  clear: both;
}

.long-row:after {
  clear: both;
}

.one-half {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  margin: 2% auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.one-third {
  width: 33.333%;
  float: left;
  margin: 2% auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.two-thirds {
  width: 66.667%;
  float: left;
  margin: 2% auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.icon-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.icons {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.section-wrap {
  margin: 4% auto;
}

.icon-heading {
  display: block;
  font-style: normal !important;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 2% 0;
}

.underline {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}


#vision {
  margin: 2% 0;
}

.right-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 25%;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

#wireframe,
#develop,
#responsive,
i {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="row">
      <div class="one-third">
        <div class="right-arrow">
          <i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <div id="wireframe">
          <img src="img/wireframe.svg" class="icons" />
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod sed do eiusmod</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="one-third">
        <div class="right-arrow">
          <i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <div id="develop">
          <img src="img/coding.svg" class="icons" />
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="one-third">
        <div id="responsive">
          <img src="img/responsive1.svg" class="icons" />
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="one-third">
          <div id="responsive">
            <img src="img/responsive.svg" class="icons" />
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="one-third">
          <div id="responsive">
            <img src="img/responsive.svg" class="icons" />
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod!</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="one-third">
          <div id="responsive">
            <img src="img/responsive.svg" class="icons" />
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: I had the first row div ending right at the bottom instead of after the last one-third div on the first row! My fault there didnt notice it at all. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the floating elements: The text makes the first `div` blocknt higher than the following ones, so the fourth one will float under the second, since there is still some "vertical space" (1px would be enough already).

The easiest way to avoid this is to extend the CSS rule for `.row` making it a flex container with flex-items inside that may wrap to the next line:

```
.row {
    max-width: 950px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Ln0r83qn/